# Does Date.now() return different value for different timezones?

Tags: javascript, java, date, java.util.date

The definition for Date.now() is not clear for me. As per definition "The Date. now() is an inbuilt function in JavaScript which returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.". So, does it mean that it will give same value for Date.now() in all timezone?
The current date and time, picked for calculation, is my local timezone or UTC ?
I have same query for java.util.Date getTime() method.

Comment: For Java I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). But yes, both of `Instant.now()` and `(new Date()).getTime()` return the same result regardless of time zone.

Comment: In Java as of 8, you should use either `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Is this for Java or for JavaScript? Do you know that http://javascriptisnotjava.com ? Fix your tags.

Comment: "Date.now()" in javascript and "new Date().getTime()" in Java. I had doubt for both the languages and both have been answered here. So, tags are correct.

Comment: can you rephrase the question so the answer 'Yes" matches? 
i.e. "Does Date.now() return the _same_ result independent of timezone?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `Date.now()` will give you the same *UTC timestamp* independent of your current timezone. Such a *timestamp*, rather a point in time, does not depend on timezones.

The Java equivalent `new Date()` gives you the exact same thing.

Check out [*Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for more information.

---

*FYI*: Don't use `new Date()` in Java as it's a legacy class. Use `Instant.now()` that is from the new [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API that is much more robust and has a nicer design.